# Display glyphicon when file input element is disabled

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Is there anyway to display the `.glyphicon-ban-circle` glyphicon on a file input element when it has been disabled (hover)? Doing the same on a button element was easy but i have yet to figure how to do the same thing on a file input. I'd prefer not to have to pull in any new dependencies if possible (bootstrap plugins).

```
 <input type="file" name="uploads" id="uploads" accept="application/pdf,image/png,image/jpeg" title="Browse" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind="
                               event: { change: fileSelected($element.files) },
                               disable: files().length > 0"/>
```

Comment: A code example or some markup would be very helpful.

Comment: @davidkonrad sorry i guess i just felt what i had wouldn't be a lot of help but i've included the element. As you can see i'm disabling the button through knockout and since i have no clue at this point on how to display a glphyicon on an input element there isn't anything there.

Comment: It changes the picture :) Thought you refered to the `<input>` `disabled` attribute. Good question ...